# how to test and mock react function/component

Tags: reactjs, django, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

this is my test for user registration using jest + react testing library, the problem is that the test update the db.

therefore at the second run the test fails (beacuse the first run registered the user)

so my question is anyone know how can I mock this function?
I will be grateful for any help I could get. thanks in advance

**the test**

```
    test('signup should dispatch signupAction', async () => {
        const middlewares = [thunk];
        const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
        initialState = {
            authReducer: { isAuthenticatedData: false },
        };
        const store = mockStore(initialState);
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <UserSignup />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
        const nameTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Name*');
        const emailTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Email*');
        const passwordTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Password*');
        const confirmTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Confirm Password*');
        const signupButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Register' });

        userEvent.type(nameTextbox, 'newtestuser');
        userEvent.type(emailTextbox, 'newtestuser@gmail.com');
        userEvent.type(passwordTextbox, 'testuser123');
        userEvent.type(confirmTextbox, 'testuser123');
        userEvent.click(signupButton);

        await waitFor(() => expect(store.getActions()[0].type).toBe('SIGNUP_SUCCESS')); 
    });
```

**sign up component**

```
const userSignup = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const isAuthenticatedData = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.isAuthenticatedData);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        re_password: '',
    });

    const [accountCreated, setAccountCreated] = useState(false);

    const { name, email, password, re_password } = formData;

    const onChange = (e) => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (password === re_password) {
            try {
                dispatch(
                    signupAction({
                        name,
                        email,
                        password,
                        re_password,
                    })
                );
                setAccountCreated(true);
            } catch {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    };

    if (isAuthenticatedData) return <Redirect to='/' />;
    if (accountCreated) return <Redirect to='/login' />;

    return (
        <div data-testid='userSignup'>
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <p>Create your Account</p>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Name*'
                        name='name'
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type='email'
                        placeholder='Email*'
                        name='email'
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='Password*'
                        name='password'
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        minLength='6'
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='Confirm Password*'
                        name='re_password'
                        value={re_password}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        minLength='6'
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <button type='submit'>Register</button>
            </form>
            <p>
                Already have an account? <Link to='/login'>Sign In</Link>
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect()(userSignup);
```

**sign up action**

```
export const signupAction =
    ({ name, email, password, re_password }) =>
    async (dispatch) => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        };

        const body = JSON.stringify({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            re_password,
        });

        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/djoser/users/`, body, config);

            dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_FAIL });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are writing unit tests (which is probably where you should start), then you are looking for a concept called "mocking." The idea is that your React unit tests should only test your React code. Your React unit tests should not depend on a database or even an API. That introduces all sorts of challenges, as you have discovered.

Basically how mocking frameworks work is you configure them with some fake data. Then when you run the tests, your code uses that fake data instead of calling the API.

I see you are using axios to call your API. I suggest you check out [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) to help you mock those axios calls.

Comment: my case is a little different, i need to mock a function(component) and not a specific endpoint and i dont see any example in the docs for this case

Comment: by the way thank you for your time I really appreciate your help man.

Comment: What function/component do you need to mock?

Comment: i need to mock the sign up component/action, basically I just want to test the signup form is working as it should be without actually changing the db

Comment: But aren't you trying to test the signup component? You can't both mock and test the same component! You mock dependencies (like your API) in order to test your component in isolation.

Comment: The point of mocking is that the original/real implementation does not get invoked. So if you were to mock your signup component, that means your signup component would not get used for your test. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: ok I understand what you say, I will correct myself i want to test that the signup action have been dispatched and handled succussfully after submitting the signup form.(after entering email, name, password and hitting the register button)

Comment: again thanks for you help man I really appreaciate it

Comment: You want to test the signup component and the signup action creator, and you don't want to affect the database. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem here is the test for those who needs it

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserSignup from '../../../components/users/UserSignup';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { signupAction } from '../../../redux/actions/auth';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
let initialState = {
    authReducer: {},
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);
jest.mock('../../../redux/actions/auth', () => ({ signupAction: jest.fn() }));


test('Redux - signup should dispatch signupAction', () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <UserSignup />
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
    initialState = {
        authReducer: { isAuthenticatedData: false },
    };
    const store = mockStore(initialState);
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <UserSignup />
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
    const nameTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Name*');
    const emailTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Email*');
    const passwordTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Password*');
    const confirmTextbox = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Confirm Password*');
    const signupButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Register' });

    const nameValue = 'testuser';
    const emailValue = 'testuser@gmail.com';
    const passwordValue = 'testuser123';
    const rePasswordValue = 'testuser123';

    userEvent.type(nameTextbox, nameValue);
    userEvent.type(emailTextbox, emailValue);
    userEvent.type(passwordTextbox, passwordValue);
    userEvent.type(confirmTextbox, rePasswordValue);
    userEvent.click(signupButton);

    const timesActionDispatched = signupAction.mock.calls.length;

    expect(timesActionDispatched).toBe(1);
    expect(signupAction.mock.calls[0][0].name).toEqual(nameValue);
    expect(signupAction.mock.calls[0][0].email).toEqual(emailValue);
    expect(signupAction.mock.calls[0][0].password).toEqual(passwordValue);
    expect(signupAction.mock.calls[0][0].re_password).toEqual(rePasswordValue);
});
```